# Printing transcript with ANSI escape sequence

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, printing

Is there a way to print a transcript generated using `script` that is coloured using [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) while preserving the colours?

I am on Mac OS X 10.6, but any tool that works on Mac OS X or on Linux that can print or create a PDF file will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scratching my own itch, I hacked a solution converting transcripts to HTML in Python. [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577349-convert-a-transcript-with-ansi-escape-sequences-to/) it is.